# Animate grow/shrink text w/o paragraph shift

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have paragraphs of text where certain words or sections in the paragraph should transition to red --> increase font-size and a few seconds later return to normal font size while maintaining the red highlight. (All of which I have functional with CSS transitions and Jquery adding the class to the span object) however - My goal is to have the grow/shrink occur without causing the surrounding paragraph text to shift/adjust/collapse as the font size increases and returns.

It should occur as shown in the image below. How can i get this effect to work and prevent the surrounding text from shifting/adjusting?

[image]

**View the SNIPPET FULL SCREEN - it looks wrong inline of the div window**

```js
$('#svcdef p').each(function(index) {
  var li = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
    li.slideDown(900);
  }, 500 * index);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#svcdef p span').addClass('cfred');
  }, 3000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#svcdef p span').removeClass('cfred');
    $('#svcdef p span').css('color', 'red');
  }, 8000);
});
```

```css
#svcdef {
  text-align: left;
  height: 820px !important;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
#svcdef p {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
#svcdef p span {
  transition: color 4s, font-size 2s ease-in-out;
}
.cfred {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#svc-content {
  height: 490px;
  float: left;
  width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color:yellow;"><b>REPUTATION MANAGEMENT</b>
</div>
<style scoped="scoped">
  p {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<br />
<div id="svcdef" class="modern-skin">
  <p><i><b>"It takes many good deeds to build a good reputation, and only one bad one to lose it."</b></i> • Benjamin Franklin
    <br>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Warren Buffet - Business magnate, Investor and philanthropist once stated "It takes 20 years to build a reputation and five minutes to ruin it. If you think about that, you’ll do things differently." Although a positive reputation for a brand and company
    does not in fact take 20 years to build, it is <span>possible</span> for a single instance of negative consumer engagement to immediately cause <span>20 years</span> or more of damage dependinging on the events that transpired and the manner in which
    the consumer shares the experience. Before the internet, many <span>companies were shielded</span> from negative events occuring with their potential customers, word of mouth remained the the primary means of communicating displeasure and the social
    network of other consumers that a negatively impacted customer could reach was curtailed and more localized. Thus damage could be more easliy mitigated or in some cases ignored.</p>
  <br />
  <p>some other paragraph
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>Yet, another useless paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, your example doesn't appear to function properly.

Comment: @nicael run the code snippet in full screen, the windowed view seems to mess it up when viewing it

Comment: One way to do this is to put the text you want to expand in a span class set to absolute and the containing paragraph set to relative. You will have to manually position the span in the paragraph. Then apply the styles to the span. The absolute positioning takes it out of the regular document flow and should not impact the rest of the document when the text is enlarged.

Comment: @DannyGibas I did think of that Danny, its a ugly way to accomplish it and the fact that this block of code is dynamically added adds some twist to that. If all else fails and there is no cleaner way to do it then i''ll consider that option again. I would have to maintain spacing in the paragraph to represent the "occupied" space of the span thats out of the dom order.

Comment: Got ya. Hopefully someone has a better answer. I would be interested in knowing a cleaner approach myself.

Comment: Looks like @nicael has a clean answer for you. Works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
body {
  font-size: 25px;
}
boo{
   display:inline-block;
   transform:scale(1);
   transition: all 100ms linear;
}
boo:hover{
  color: red;
  transform:scale(2);
  transition: all 100ms linear;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>This is the test sentence</li>
<li>This is the <boo>test (hover me ;)</boo> sentence</li>
<li>This is the test sentence</li>
</ol>
```

Example with jQuery:

```js
var boo = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    boo==0?$("boo").addClass("booable"):$("boo").removeClass("booable");
    boo=!boo;
},100)
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 25px;
}
boo {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.booable{
  color: red;
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 100ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>This is the test sentence</li>
  <li>This is the <boo>test</boo> sentence</li>
  <li>This is the test sentence</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for except it being a hover effect, I'll need to modify it to work with the Jquery method being used, but if i can get that to work, i'll accept that! +1 either way, thanks!

Comment: take a look at this jsfiddle with your code added, i get the color shift but no transform. You maybe have an explanation as to why the behavior works for :hover but not for .addClass() ?  [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qhr14wh4/2/)

Comment: @DMS in your example, remove `transform:scale(1);`.